# In WooCommerce, how can I have children variations?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So imagine you have, for a sofa, leather and fabric, and each different colors. On the website it'll show in a way that only the colours inside that parent variation appear when that parent variation is clicked.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Yes that is possible.

Comment: And how can that be achieved?

Comment: That's a different question. Close this then re-op a new question. Be sure to include your attempt so far as this is not a 'do this for me' website. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @nakkeru You can edit your question and you don't need to reopen a new one… I you haven't any code for it, this question can be of-topic as it will ask software or tutorial recommendations…